# Adding dummy where condition brings execution plan to seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Could you please have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7ad28/8 and help me in understanding why adding a where condition will bring index on seek from scan? As per my (wrong) understanding, It should not have made any difference since its a greater then condition which should have caused scan.

I am also pasting table script and queries in question below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mappings]
(
[MappingID] [smallint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
[ProductID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[CategoryID] [smallint] NOT NULL
) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Mappings] ADD CONSTRAINT [pk_Mappings_MappingID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MappingID]) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_Mappings_ProductIDCategoryID] ON [dbo].[Mappings] ([ProductID], [CategoryID]) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerProducts]
(
[CustomerID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[SomeDate] [datetimeoffset] (0) NULL,
[SomeAttribute] [bigint] NULL
) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerProducts] ADD CONSTRAINT [pk_CustomerProducts_ProductIDCustomerID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductID], [CustomerID]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

 
--SCAN [tempdb].[dbo].[Mappings].[nc_Mappings_ProductIDCategoryID].(NonClustered)   
SELECT b.[SomeDate],
       b.[SomeAttribute]
FROM dbo.[Mappings] a
    INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerProducts b
        ON a.[ProductID] = b.[ProductID]
Where b.CustomerID = 88;

--SEEK [tempdb].[dbo].[Mappings].[nc_Mappings_ProductIDCategoryID].(NonClustered)   
SELECT b.[SomeDate],
       b.[SomeAttribute]
FROM dbo.[Mappings] a
    INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerProducts b
        ON a.[ProductID] = b.[ProductID]
           AND b.CustomerID = 88
Where a.[ProductID] > 0;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

"It should not have made any difference since its a greater then condition which should have caused scan."

You added an explicit predicate (ProductID > 0) so SQL Server chooses to seek on that value (0) then range scan.  To see this, select the Index Seek on Mappings, open the Properties Tab, and look for Seek Predicates, and expand the entire tree of results.  You'll see Start and applicable range scan attributes underneath.

So if you had real data (pretend you have ProductIDs from 1-100), and have a WHERE ProductID > 77.  You'll seek in the B-Tree to ProductID 77, then RANGE SCAN the remainder of the non-clustered index.

Watch this: this'll help you visualize and understand what happens internally in different index operations (disclaimer: this is me presenting)
https://youtu.be/fDd4lw6DfqU?t=748

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the plans look like:

[image: execution plans]

Hovered in yellow is the information on the `clustered index seek` from table `CustomerProducts`. The seek predicate is set to the value of the condition `[ProductID] > 0` which is perfectly reasonable as part of the join condition is `a.[ProductID] = b.[ProductID]` and also `a.[ProductID] > 0` in the where clause. This means that *`b.[ProductID] > 0`*. As `ProductID` is the **first column** on the clustered index, any information that reduces the lookup can be used. [The seek operation should be faster than the scan](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/277/index-scans-and-table-scans/#:%7E:text=An%20index%20scan%20or%20table,needed%20to%20satisfy%20the%20query.&text=Here%20we%20can%20see%20that,doing%20a%20Clustered%20Index%20Scan.), so the optimizer will try to do that.